# How often are updates retrieved by the Android LocationManager for requestLocationUpdates()?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have a question about the requestLocationUpdates method.

How often does the method get updates when the minTime is specified as 0?

Does it default to 6000, or some device specific number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use 0, the system is supposed to provide updates as fast as it can. The usual order of magnitude is once per second, but it is device specific.

see also the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)